# What are some ways to work with / search flagged emails on iOS?

Tags: ios, email

The Mail App on iOS 5 adds support for flagging emails, but I can't seem to find a way to actually put this feature to use.

Is there a way to search for flagged emails?

Is there a way to cleverly auto-filter flagged emails into a folder?

I know that using GMail as an IMAP server automatically duplicates flagged messages in the "Starred" folder - but if you are using another email service, is there any way to make flags useful on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS5 there is no way to easily find flagged emails.

But in the public preview of iOS 6 at WWDC (hence not under NDA), Apple showed off a new "Flagged" top level folder in the iOS Mail App, as well as a special folder for email from senders marked as VIP's.

So it appears that the ultimate answer to this questions is: upgrade to iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS there's very little you can actually do with the flags except for visual cues.

On the Mac however, you can filter flagged email into a *Smart Mailbox* which will keep a live view of your mail matching search criteria, such as mail flags.

Comment: Is there any way to get a Smart Mailbox to display on an iOS device?  Or - to use a Smart Mailbox to actually filter into real IMAP folders that might display?

Comment: Unfortunately no.